# Castle Windsor bug: Resolving singleton through child container

Tags: castle-windsor, asp.net-web-api, castle

This fails with an ObjectDisposedException when trying to assert:

```
    [Test]
    public void Resolve_SingletonAndDisposeChildContainer_ShouldNotDisposeSingleton()
    {
        // arrange
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Register(Component.For<ISomeFactory>().AsFactory());
        container.Register(Component.For<A>());

        // uncomment the line below and the test will not fail
        //container.Resolve<ISomeFactory>();

        var childContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        container.AddChildContainer(childContainer);

        // act
        var someFactory = childContainer.Resolve<ISomeFactory>();
        container.RemoveChildContainer(childContainer);
        childContainer.Dispose();

        someFactory = container.Resolve<ISomeFactory>();

        // assert
        Assert.That(someFactory.Create(), Is.Not.Null);
    }
```

The reason is (probably) because the singleton is handled by the lifestylemanager in the child container and is therefore disposed. This is causing some issues with child-container handling in the MVC Web API, so I am really keen on finding a solution.

Does anyone know of a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: Its reproducible in version 3.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed a bug. [I put it in the issue tracker](http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-345). It is fixed in trunk and will be fixed in v3.1